# How to display soft deleted users when searching through searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

I am using searchkick to perform search for users. However it does not display the soft-deleted user's record. I have tried using unscoped too, but that does not work either.

```
User.unscoped.all.search search_param, fields: [:id, :email, :first_name, :last_name], match: :word_middle
```

Is there a way I could display soft-deleted users record when using searchkick?

Comment: Why and how are soft-deleted users excluded from the query in the first place? Did you implement this feature yourself or do you use a gem (which one)?

Comment: It's the spree_user model. When querying through, it omits the user whose deleted_at field is not nil. However unscoping it shows the result for all on normal active record query but does not work with searchkick.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is that the soft-deleted records are not in the elastic search index at all? Perhaps there's a hook somewhere removing them when they're soft-deleted?

Answer (score 0):

got the same experience on mongoid_paranoia gem. when you call the model#destroy method, it removes the record from the elasticsearch as well. so one solution is to reindex the model using "after_destroy" callback.